# как внести ограничение на аргументы шаблона класса

Tags: c++

У меня есть:

```
template < typename IntType = double>
class Matrix {...};
```

Но разрешить создание матрицы с любым типом, думаю не логично.  Как сделать так, чтобы инстанцирование было возможно только со встроенными типами и с типами из иерархии какого то класса(условный  `Base`) ?   Какое решение вы бы приняли сами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы использовал `static_assert`:

```
template <typename T = double>
class Matrix
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<T> || std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>,
                  "The type must be arithmetic or be derived from `Base`.");
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Да,  это какраз то, что нужно.

Comment: только: почему не  std::is_arithmetic<IntType>() а  std::is_arithmetic_v<T> ?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Здесь можно и так и так, большой разницы нет. Просто этот вариант мне нравится больше.

Comment: Просто ваш вариант может быть неизвестен многим компиляторам.  Мне кажется предпочтительней варианты, которые известны всем компиляторам.  Какого ваше мнение по этому поводу?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Обычно меня устраивает, если мой код компилируется на более-менее новых версиях основных компиляторов (GCC, Clang, и, желательно, MSVC), поэтому я не ограничиваю себя в использовании новых крутых примочек. :) Если нужно или хочется поддерживать более старые версии компиляторов или более редкие компиляторы, тогда другое дело.

Comment: Теперь  все вопросы исчерпаны, спасибо за все ответы